# Has a past data outside sliding window any Influence on learning of a LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series

I am getting into LSTM  and I have one technical question. I have time  series in 1 minute interval and 2 weeks data.  I need predict every next minute in the future. One sliding window has 120 minutes length. My question is, if " the past data outside  of one sliding window" has an influence on training and testing in current window of a LSTM ?  Different way  - could be  the sliding windows from the 2 weeks mixed randomly for training ( out of any order) ? Thank`s.

Comment: any answer on this?